# Breakpoints in Visual Studio 2019 not working for Angular multi-project workspace and Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-2019, single-page-application

As the complexity of our clientapp grows, we are migrating our angular project to a multi-project workspace. The project builds correctly and starts the angular client from the new project structure in debugging mode. I have set ***spa.Options.SourcePath*** to the root folder of the multi-project angular workspace. I believe the build hits the package.json within this folder and builds the angular default application but the debugger is not capable to find the sourcecode to bind the breakpoints inside ***/projects/my-project***.

I am using the latest Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices and Angular version 10.1.4.

Is there some configuration I could use to bind the breakpoints and have debugging inside Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you want to debug the js file or  any other files? If you want to debug the js file, you should check `Enable Javascript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE)` under Tools-->Debugging-->General.

Comment: I want to debug the ts file, and I am aware of the option you mentioned. As I said, we are migrating the angular workspace type and in the normal workspace type, the debugger works as expected. thank you